# What are these wedges in the framing of my house?

Tags: framing

I found an incomplete small [spandrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spandrel) under my stairs, and whilst I was exploring I found these wedges under the framing of some sort.

**What are these "things" called, and what do they do?**

[image]

Comment: It could be spacer, used during erection to maintain the levelness of the beam. If it is, it should be easily moved by hand.

Comment: Look likes a shim  to me.  It is shimming.

Comment: Both are right, but in this case seems more like a spacer to give support to X marked beam, than to shim beam in position.

Comment: Bog standard shims.